# Facing issue in localization test for German , Turkish and Spanish(Spain and Mexico)

Tags: python, robotframework, pyautogui

I am using pyautogui python library to print symbols in Spanish, German and Turkish language
but through automation it is giving different output and When I am typing it manually it is printing different symbols

Steps:
1)Created robot script

```
Spanish_Spain_Fragment_Win_Edge_Localization_Typing
  [Documentation]     Test to check typing test in for spainsh sapin language
  [Tags]     fragment      spain
  open browser      ${url}     edge
  maximize browser window
  Sleep    2
  ${result}=    spanishS
  log  result: ${result}
  sleep    2
  click button      xpath://button[@id='submit-btn']
  sleep    1
  ${eng}=  english
  sleep    2
  ${abc}=       get value       xpath://textarea[@id='text_area2']
  log to console    ${abc}
  should be equal as strings      ${spain}      ${abc}
  close browser
```

2. spanishS python file which I have written in pyautogui

   pi.typewrite('`') pi.press('space') pi.typewrite('1') pi.press('space') pi.typewrite('2') pi.press('space') pi.typewrite('3') pi.press('space') pi.typewrite('4') pi.press('space') pi.typewrite('5') pi.press('space') pi.typewrite('6') pi.press('space') pi.typewrite('7') pi.press('space') pi.typewrite('8') pi.press('space') pi.typewrite('9') pi.press('space') pi.typewrite('0') pi.press('space') pi.typewrite('-') pi.press('space') pi.typewrite('=') pi.press('space') pi.typewrite('[') pi.press('space') pi.typewrite(']') pi.press('space') pi.typewrite('\\') pi.press('space') pi.typewrite(';') pi.press('space') pi.hotkey("'") pi.press('space') pi.typewrite(',') pi.press('space') pi.typewrite('.') pi.press('space') pi.typewrite('/') pi.press('space') pi.hotkey('shift', '`')
   pi.press('space')
   pi.hotkey('shift', '1')
   pi.press('space')
   pi.hotkey('shift', '2')
   pi.press('space')
   pi.hotkey('shift', '3')
   pi.press('space')
   pi.hotkey('shift', '4')
   pi.press('space')
   pi.hotkey('shift', '5')
   pi.press('space')
   pi.hotkey('shift', '6')
   pi.press('space')
   pi.hotkey('shift', '7')
   pi.press('space')
   pi.hotkey('shift', '8')
   pi.press('space')
   pi.hotkey('shift', '9')
   pi.press('space')
   pi.hotkey('shift', '0')
   pi.press('space')
   pi.hotkey('shift', '-')
   pi.press('space')
   pi.hotkey('shift', '=')
   pi.press('space')
   pi.hotkey('shift', '[')
   pi.press('space')
   pi.hotkey('shift', ']')
   pi.press('space')
   pi.hotkey('shift', '\')
   pi.press('space')
   pi.hotkey('shift', ';')
   pi.press('space')
   pi.hotkey('shift', "'")
   pi.press('space')
   pi.hotkey('shift', ',')
   pi.press('space')
   pi.hotkey('shift', '.')
   pi.press('space')
   pi.hotkey('shift', '/')

Error: If I am running the robot script different symbols are printing and If I am typing it manually different symbols are printing
**Symbols Generated Through Automation**

```
ñ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 - + ' ¡ º ` , . ç Ñ ! " · $ % & / ( ) = _ * ? ¿ ª ^ ; : Ç
```

**Same symbol generated by typing it manually**

```
º 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 ' ¡ `+ ç ñ ´, . - ª ! " · $ % & / ( ) = ? ¿ ^* Ç Ñ ¨; : _
```

The same is happing for Turkish and German Keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a difference in the keyboard code page in Python and in the Browser.

You should try to change the code page or language settings.

Comment: Can you elaborate the process how to do that?

Comment: You should try to activate the keyboard mapping on your system. Maybe in python you can do that. Take a look on how a keyboard layout is for each county. For example in my Portuguese keyboard I have the symbol 'ç' at the right of the L key, and I know that the German would be different.